# Correct regex expression for including whitespace within a match only

Tags: c#, regex

I have this sample of string `Lorem ipsum +12 121 323 454 dolor sit amet`. Here is my RegEx `([0-9+?\s])` but it includes outside spaces.

[image]

Comment: Use a look around: `(?<=^|\s)([\d+?\s]+)(?=\s|$)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a nonspace and end with nonspace:

```
[0-9+](?:([0-9+?\s]*[0-9+]))?
```

A digit or a plus, followed optionally by any number of digits, plusses or spaces, finally ending in a digit or a plus.

Answer (score 1):

You are just matching a single character with `([0-9+?\s])` that also matches a whitespace char with `\s`, that is why you are also matching "single" spaces.

You can use whitespace boundaries to the left and right, than match an optional plus sign at the start followed by 1 or more digits and then optionally repeat 1 or more whitespace characters followed by again 1 or more digits.

```
(?<!\S)\+?\d+(?:\s+\d+)*(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIVlFJ/1)